# Power BI - How to ignore a slicer for one measure, but apply it on another?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm new to power bi and DAX so I'll try to be as clear as I possibly can.

Here's the
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1jyP.png)
I'm dealing with.
The X axis shows the hours of the day. Each bar shows data of a specific location, yet it's possible that two different bars would show the same location because of a time difference (hours on the X axis).
What I'm trying to do is to SUM a cloumn, grouped by location.

Example:
The number 704 (registered users) shown on the third bar (tooltip) also apears on the second because it's data from the same location. In this case I only want to sum it once. The first bar shows 540 registered users from a different location, so in total, the new measure I'm trying to display across all bars would show the number 1244 (704+540).

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Gilad

Comment: In order to ignore Slicer you need to ignore filter context created by that slicer. And to adjust/ignore Filter Context, you need to use Calculate/Calculate table function. please read more about it here:  http://sqlblog.com/blogs/marco_russo/archive/2010/01/03/how-calculate-works-in-dax.aspx